# How to capture screen on iOS 10 by using AssistiveTouch?

Tags: ios

As my iPhone Home Button was broken, I use AssistiveTouch to help me to operate the phone.

But when I upgrade to iOS 10, I try to capture screen by using AssistiveTouch Home Button + power button, I cannot get the screen correctly as the AssistiveTouch menu is still on the screen.

Any work around? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the assistive touch menu you've to select: device -> more -> screenshot.